# pandas datetime to transform new date format (hour-minute-second)?

Tags: pandas

I want to transform `df['time']` to hour-minute-second format in a new series `df['t']`(e.g. 00:02:58 ).

```
1713   2019-09-24 00:02:58
1714   2019-09-24 00:12:11
1715   2019-09-24 00:13:42
……
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Trying:

`pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S')` still gets the same format.

```
1713   2019-09-24 00:02:58
1714   2019-09-24 00:12:11
1715   2019-09-24 00:13:42
……
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Update:

I want datetime formats.

Comment: Isn't your column already in datetime format then?

Comment: yes, original columns format is datetime.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to have `timedelta`:

```
df['new_time'] = df['time'] - df['time'].dt.normalize()
```

output:

```
                    time new_time
1713 2019-09-24 00:02:58 00:02:58
1714 2019-09-24 00:12:11 00:12:11
1715 2019-09-24 00:13:42 00:13:42
```

which then allows you to access other info easily, e.g

```
df.new_time.dt.seconds
```

gives:

```
1713    178
1714    731
1715    822
Name: new_time, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `dt.time`:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.time
```

Comment: @Jack Mine is too

Comment: I get object type, which pandas version did you use? see this link also https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-dt-time/